# Handlebars Equal Nested

Tags: html, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I have 2 Nested Eachs, And I want to check to Data to Show a text on a Specific State.
But It's Not Working.

Here's The Code :

```
{{#each foods}}
 {{#each this.branches}}

      {{#equal this.branch._id "5ff6be7b5fd0654977582375"}} //Works
        <h1 class="itemtext">Works</h1>
      {{/equal}}

      {{#equal ../../user._id "5ff6be7b5fd0654977582375"}}
        <h1 class="itemtext">Works</h1>
      {{/equal}}

      {{#equal ../../user._id this.branch._id}} //Not Working
        <h1 class="itemtext">Not Working</h1>
      {{/equal}}

 {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

And I'm Using This Helper For Handlebars :

```
npm handlebars-helper-equal
```

What Seems to be the Problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: {#each this.branches}} should be {{#each this.branches}}

Comment: @Wimanicesir My Problem is in {{#equal ../../user._id this.branch._id}} Section. Even though its true, It doesn't render